# slack files.Upload in node fails with invalid_arg_name

Tags: node.js, axios, slack, slack-api, glitch-framework

I'm trying and failing to get a file from s3 to a slack file, via a node bot hosted on glitch.

The glitch project I'm cloning uses axiom to make web requests. I'm making a request to read the s3 file into a string, then taking the contents and putting it into a request to [files.upload](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload). Files.upload takes form data via a post.

I'm not entirely clear on how to structure the form data "file" parameter to take a string, but the following returns an "invalid_arg_name" error.

```
  var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
  // ...

  const upload = new FormData();
  upload.append("channels", destinationChannel);
  const s = new Readable();
  s.push("example s3 file content string");
  s.push(null);
  upload.append("file", s); 

  const config = { 
    headers: {'Authorization': "Bearer " + myAccessToken},
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  };

  axios.post(`${apiUrl}/files.upload`, upload, config)
    .then((result) => { 
      console.log('uploaded file'); 
      console.log(result.data);
   });
```

The docs also say it takes a url-encoded form, but I'm not sure what structure that will take *or* if it will cope with the 10s of kilobytes of files I want to send via this method.

If we can fix this method, that would be great, but if there's an easier way to feed a public URL to slack's files.upload, I'll take that as well.

Comment: Could you try instead of sending a file send content? `upload.append("content", "some string");` the readable looks a little unintuitive. and the config too (i would asume content type beeing in `header`)

Comment: would the post line be different for `content`? with content instead I still get the invalid_arg_name error. same with or without the content-type.

Comment: For content it should just be fórm urlencoded.... but i think you have an other problem... you could use a servie like https://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2 to debug and see what request you are sending

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work, even with a 3k line log file, using url encoding through querystring:

```
const upload = {
  channels: channel,
  content: "s3 file content",
};

console.log(upload);
const config = { 
  headers: { 'Authorization': "Bearer " + myAccessToken },
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
};
axios.post(`${apiUrl}/files.upload`, qs.stringify(upload), config)
  .then((result) => { 
    console.log('uploaded file'); 
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('err on files upload %0', err);
  });
```

I'm not sure at what size this will break down, so I'd love to get formdata working somehow.